# How would you refer to someone outside the gender binary in french?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre, genre-biologique

If you were referring to a person who identified as gender neutral (did not identify their gender as either male or female), how would you refer to them in French, since it is a heavily gendered language?

In English, you would refer to them as they, zir, xe, etc., whatever their preferred pronoun was. But since the French language seems to revolve around gendered words, how would you refer to them while still respecting their gender identity?

I know there is the "masculine over feminine" rule, but would there be an exception here?

Comment: Could you give an exemple which bothers you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no accepted neutral pronoun.

You might refer to that person by using both masculine and feminine pronouns combined (*il/elle*), or forms that don't indicate a specific gender (*cette personne*, *cet individu*)

Answer (score 4):

In most ambiguous situation (mixed groups, unknown sex), you should use the masculine. You could also use ”*on*” when possible.

Pay attention to the vocabulary you use, however. “*Personne*”, for example, can be used to designate someone regardless of its gender; it’s still feminine.

> Une trentaine de personnes étaient présentes à la réunion des anciens de l’école pour hommes de Sainte-Gudule-en-Ardèche.

Answer (score 0):

Toute personne connaissant le français, qu'elle soit une personnalité de la vie politique ou une brute a moitie analphabète, devrait se rendre compte assez rapidement que s'il y a une corrélation entre le genre des mots employés et le sexe -- qu'il soit biologique ou social, ressenti ou imposé -- des personnes désignées, passer de cette corrélation à une détermination est un exercice voué à l'échec.  A l'heure des mamans, les papas ne sont pas si rares que ça à venir rechercher leur progéniture qui elle même peut être pourvue d'attributs mâles.  Si vous parlez des institutrices de l’école de votre enfant (qui lui peut être pourvu d'attributs féminins), des infirmières qui vous ont soigné, il n'est pas impossible que des hommes soient compris dans le collectif, n'en déplaise aux grammairiens qui oublient de regarder l'usage. La sentinelle surveillant l'approche de l'ennemi, l'estafette allant chercher des troupes en renfort, celles-ci même, ont plus de chances d’être des hommes que le médecin qui soignera les blessés après la bataille.

Si vous pensez que changer la langue fera changer les mentalités (personnellement, je pense qu'il en ira dans l'autre direction), plutôt que de la tordre, poussez-la sur sa pente naturelle, favorisez l'accord à la majorité, au plus proche -- usages répandus depuis longtemps que certains grammairiens ont cherchés à combattre sans jamais réussir à les supprimer --  et plutôt que de chercher à augmenter les relations entre genre et sexe, cherchez au contraire à rendre plus commune la conscience de la rupture entre ces deux notions et de l'artificialité d'une règle que l'on applique uniquement parce qu'on nous a enseigné que c'était la règle.

Comment: Je n'ai visiblement pas compris la question de la même façon que toi.

Comment: Il demande quelle pronoms additionnels utiliser pour ceux qui ne s'identifie ni comme homme, ni comme femme.  Ma réponse est que le genre grammatical des mots n'a déjà pas un rapport fort avec le sexe (ou le genre) des personnes désignées et qu'il vaut mieux chercher a affaiblir ce rapport qu'a le renforcer (ce que de nouveaux pronoms feraient).

Comment: Concrètement tu suggères de changer le français en remplaçant « il/lui » et « elle » par un pronom unique (« iellui » ?) pour que la question ne se pose même pas ? Je crois que la question est bien plus concrète et demande comment s'en sortir dans dans le français réel d'aujourd'hui.

Comment: Y a-t-il un réel antagonisme entre `une personnalité de la vie politique` et `une brute à moitié analphabète` ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, je suis pour affaiblir le lien entre genre grammatical et sexe ou genre social (et je tentais de montrer qu'il n’était déjà pas si fort que cela), pas pour le renforcer ce que ferait l'introduction de nouveau pronoms (qu'on accorderait comment?)

Comment: @M42, en France les personnalités de la vie politique ont tendance a mettre en avant une certaine culture, elles écrivent des recueils de poèmes, des biographies de personnages historiques, se retrouvent à l’Académie française... difficile de les dire analphabètes (pour brutes, je ne me prononce pas).

Comment: Toutes ne se retrouvent pas à l'Académie, loin s'en faut. Je pense, au hasard, à Nadine Morano ou autres de la même veine.

Comment: J'allais évoquer Morano comme illustre contre exemple aussi, sans oublier Douillet. Sinon, @unFrancophone, ta réponse n'a pas de rapport avec la question (qui est purement linguistique).

Comment: +1 J'apprécie l'exercice de style.